# ATI Driver issues - 13.10

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, xubuntu

I am installing Xubuntu 13.10 on an old laptop I have.  When I boot up to the installer, the display is fine, everything seems to be working perfectly, however, on the Xubuntu boot screen, the colours all look weird (they're all pink and green).  I noticed the same when I had Kubuntu running on it, and I just figured that it was because the system wasn't powerful enough for Kubuntu.

Now I'm thinking it has to be a display driver issue.  But how do I fix it?  The laptop has an ATI Mobile Radeon 7500 card, so I suppose I need to install the right drivers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the driver using

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

and this did the trick!